# How to disable RC4 on postfix?

Tags: postfix, tls

I have make a security check of our postfix server on https://de.ssl-tools.net/mailservers and get a warning that "ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" is still supported. But don't know how to disable that ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add to your main.cf:

```
# TLS Server
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
# TLS Client
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
```

Comment: Why did you add the `aNULL` cipher to that list?

Comment: To block anonymous DH and ECDH algorithms. It's not strictly necessary for this question, but typically you always want the server to be authenticated to avoid MITM attacks.